# Predicting map using maxent software

Tags: maxent

I am in the process of developing predicting map in MAXENT. I have current data of distribution of my trees species in tropical forest. I need to use Maxent software and Arcgis 10.3 to find the potential area where this tree species can be found. My preoccupation is to know which environmental data and where can I find it to realize my predicting map, and how can I use Maxent software to do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is species modeling specific software

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  Unfortunately, this question is quite broad -- There is a great deal of information which could impact your model, and no way for us to know what is available or applicable to your requirements.

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS While it may be used for a very specific reason, there are other questions here about [tag:maxent], and this question does appear to be relating to doing a spatial analysis.

Comment: @EvilGenius 24 I have no issue with that. At some point you have to draw a boundary on gis and for me Maxent is a step too far. For others it is not and that is fine, it is why multiple votes are needed. This is how sites such as this work. I would say though, just because some have asked questions wit this tag in the past does not make current questions valid (in and of itself).